# Mean Free Path of Magnetic Core

Tags: electric-machine, magnetic-flux, flux

[image]

I don't understand how they got the mean free paths (ls) of each leg. I know that I should be calculating the longest + the shortest paths and divide them by two, but I don't know HOW I should be calculating these.

Thanks

Comment: 'mean free path' is a phrase from a different branch of science. I think you mean 'effective length', though 'mean length' might be a simpler and adequate approximation.

Comment: I meant to say, mean length path*

Comment: or yes the effective length

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did the answer:

To find, for example, the mean length of the one at the left:
I started by finding the longest way: started at the middle of the 15 cm, added it all the way to the left then upwards then back to the middle of the 15 cms.

Then I found the shortest way by starting again at the middle of 15 cms then adding until the corner of the square, then upwards to the second corner and then back to the middle of the 15 cms.

I added both "routes" i took and divided by two to obtain the average.